# solr - sort terms in the /terms component in ascending document frequency order

Tags: solr

In solr in the `/terms` query I get the terms in the document frequency df descending order.

However I'd like to get the terms listed in the ascending order, i.e. terms with the least document frequency listed first.

The solr wiki has a sort field `terms.sort` there is nothing about asc, desc orderc

```
Defines how to sort the terms returned. Valid options are count, 
which sorts by the term frequency, with the highest term frequency 
first, or index, which sorts in index order.

Example: terms.sort=index
```

Comment: This is a work around: Use `terms.sort=count` and read the results from the resultset in the reverse order.

Comment: I'll have a look into this. Thank you Binoy Dalal.